# If-statement/Conditional argument not working in Geany (PYTHON)

Tags: python, windows, if-statement, geany, controlpanel

```
age = 19
age == 18
```

Control panel is supposed to show FALSE but it is showing nothing.

[Control Panel Image Below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctBos.png)

Comment: To display the values of variables, you need to use the print statement like `print(age)`

Comment: It works as advertised in the default Python interpreter. You may be following a bad tutorial if it does not mention that detail.

Answer (score 0):

You defined a variable called "age" and asigned it the integer 19. You then stated that the variable called "age" is euqal to the integer 18. Now in order to see any output, you need to print your variable to the screen. In order to print something you use print().

For example:

```
x = "apples"
print(x)

y = "banana"
print(y)
```

If you want to see whether something is true or false you can do something like this.

```
age = 18

true_or_false = age > 19

print(true_or_false)
```